# ffmpeg: demux a section of a file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have an interesting challenge that I think can be solved with ffmpeg. I'm being sent the first few hundred kb of a file (mov/prores or h.264), and a 1-2 meg chunk from the same file, closer to its end. I need to demux the larger portion, pulling out the audio as a wav file for later processing.

I've tried concatenating those first few hundred k to the later section (bash shell commands), then demuxing the result. However this understandably results in repeated `invalid frame header` errors (full output is below).

Because I have access to the beginning of the file, running `ffprobe -i` on that section works fine. I had hoped to use this information to 'force' the format when demuxing the latter portion. However I'm clearly not passing enough parameters to get ffmpeg to demux the audio:

```
    $ ffmpeg -f mov -i prores_last_2_megs.mov output_audio.wav
ffmpeg version 2.8.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fbb6c804200] moov atom not found
prores_last_2_megs.mov: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Below is output from a demux attempt, using first 150k of original file and a 4 meg chuck from later in that file:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i prores_first_150k_and_last_4_megs.mov -to 00:00:02 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 cut.mov
ffmpeg version 2.8.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    [prores @ 0x7fee0880be00] invalid frame header
        Last message repeated 20 times
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fee08808000] decoding for stream 0 failed
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fee08808000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), none(bt709), 1920x1080, 124460 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
    Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'prores_first_150k_and_last_4_megs.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt
        creation_time   : 2015-11-03 10:23:58
        timecode        : 2332:32:21;21
      Duration: 00:04:02.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 136 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), none(bt709), 1920x1080, 124460 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 2997 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2015-11-03 10:23:58
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2015-11-03 10:23:58
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
        Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2015-11-03 10:23:58
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          timecode        : 2332:32:21;21
    File 'cut.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
    [mov @ 0x7fee09800000] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
    [mov @ 0x7fee09800000] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
    Output #0, mov, to 'cut.mov':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt
        minor_version   : 537199360
        compatible_brands: qt
        timecode        : 2332:32:21;21
        encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), none, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 124460 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 2997 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2015-11-03 10:23:58
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
          encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, 1536 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2015-11-03 10:23:58
          handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=   21 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4011kB time=00:00:01.49 bitrate=21911.0kbits/s
    video:3727kB audio:281kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.056156%
```

I could possibly slice the header more intelligently (e.g. for prores, slice from the head up to the `mdia` atom, then concatenate to the latter portion once I've determine how to slice that on a proper frame boundary...

So, if you were given the first few hundred k and a subsequent 2-meg chunk from the middle of a video file, how would you extract wav audio? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to listen the audio with VLC? Note that if it works you can always redirect (save) the audio output to file ... and you can dedicate to your challenge more light... :)

Comment: You may have to do this using a video repair tool. So, first file should be moov + some of mdia. 2nd should be your media payload. Then use [this](http://www.videohelp.com/software/recover-mp4-to-h264).